# "Splicing" Code into a Windows Executable

Tags: .net, c, windows

I have two windows console applications that I have written in C.

I don't have the source code for either of them.

I want to produce a single .exe file that runs both.

What are my options?

What if the second application is .Net code instead of C? Do I need to take special steps to load the .Net runtimes?

I am aware that I'm doing something horribly wrong if I need to know the answer to this question, so don't bother pointing that out :-P

Comment: Option 1: Re-write your code.  Option 2: Use a `.bat` file.  Option 3: Don't expect SO to help with your nefarious schemes.

Comment: I am aware that I'm doing something horribly wrong if I need to know the answer to this question, so don't bother pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just go the simple way, store both exe's as resources or as binary arrays(see [bin2c](http://www.programmersheaven.com/download/17063/download.aspx)), write them out as temp files at run time, then execute them(either through `CreateProcess`, `spawn` or via a `system` command).

The other way would be to write your own variants or reverse engineer the ones you have(just make sure to keep it legal & professional, ie: if you didn't originally write them, don't even think of profiting off them and/or not giving credits where its due)

Comment: Writing out files just to execute them seems gross. Is there any way to "reverse" memory-map files in Windows? So I would make my in-memory buffer *look* like a file to the Windows API, but really it's not?

Comment: You mean execute it from memory? Its possible, falls under a technique called manual mapping, game-deception.com has a few examples of manually mapping dlls, just apply the same to exes